# Calling a config value in Python to trigger a function

Tags: python, timer, subprocess

I'm still a newbie to Python but I was wondering if it was possible to have it call on a config file to determine if it should call on a function or not.

Basically, I've written an init.py that calls on another .py file called process.py (which does file processing). I've also written another script called timer.py that calls on process.py every 60 minutes.

What I'd ideally like to accomplish is have init.py executed, which'll call on process.py using subprocess, but IF HourlyRun=1 IN Settings.cfg, THEN:

Not entirely sure where to get started on the config side. I'm at work now so I'll edit in my init.py code thus far when I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html ConfigParser to read from your Settings.cfg and take actions depending on the value read.ç

For example:

```
sample_config = """[yourConfig] HourlyRun=1"""
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.readfp(io.BytesIO(sample_config))
if config.get("yourConfig", "HourlyRun")==1 then ...
```